# MYSQL If then where

Tags: mysql

i'm trying using if then where statement but no success, here my code

```
    SELECT * FROM mahasiswa
IF (id_jns_daftar = 2) THEN
INNER JOIN kuliahmhs on mahasiswa.id_reg_pd = kuliahmhs.id_reg_pd
WHERE NULLIF(sks_diakui, '') IS NULL 
OR NULLIF(sks_diakui, ' ') IS NULL
OR NULLIF(sks_diakui, '  ') IS NULL
OR NULLIF(sks_diakui, '-') IS NULL
OR NULLIF(sks_diakui, '--') IS NULL
OR NULLIF(sks_diakui, '---') IS NULL
OR NULLIF(sks_diakui, 0) IS NULL
OR NULLIF(sks_diakui, '0') IS NULL
OR sks_diakui != sks_total
```

The point is, if id_jns_daftar = 2 then check other column that is NULL and show the result only that id_jns_daftar = 2

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Can you provide some sample data and the result you'd want to get for it?

Comment: Also, can you explain what you're trying to do with those `nullif`s? I doubt they really do what you intended.

Comment: the NULLIF is using for show the data that have wrong value such only space or - or --. I just want show the data that have wrong value if it has id_jns_daftar = 2.